# combined usage of shorthand c if else statement and break in a loop resulted an error

Tags: c, conditional-operator

I'm now writing the score counting logic for a simple game "Simon says" and trying to use the shortened if else statement ():

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
   char simonPattern[50];
   char userPattern[50];
   int userScore;
   int i;

   userScore = 0;
   strcpy(simonPattern, "RRGBRYYBGY");
   strcpy(userPattern, "RRGBBRYBGY");

   for (i=0;i<10;i++){
      (simonPattern[i] == userPattern[i] )?( userScore++ ): (break);
      }


   printf("userScore: %d\n", userScore);

   return 0;
}
```

and this line resulted in an error when compiling:

```
main.c:15:62: error: expected expression before ‘break’
```

Then I tried to write the shortened if statement in a more traditional format:

```
  if (simonPattern[i] == userPattern[i]){
     userScore++;
     }
  else{
     break;
     }
```

It went through without any problem and the program ran with no error in score calculation.

Did I use the if statement wrong? Or it's just not supported to use break in shorthand if statement?

Thanks for the help！

Comment: The "shorthand if statement" isn't a statement, it's an expression.  And the components have to be expressions not statements.

Comment: if you strive for brevity - you can write `for (i=0;i<10 && simonPattern[i] == userPattern[i];i++, userScore++) ;`

Comment: Please stop using the book that called this a "shorthand if statement". It is the ternary operator and operators work with expression. Here `break` is a statement.

Comment: Or at least understand where it can function that way. A *ternary* can function like a shorthand `if` for *assignment* or *parameter* selection. Not for alternate statement execution. It is a ternary operator -- not a full shorthand for `if`.

Comment: What the purpose you try to support by using any shorthand? Less characters in your program? Why? Faster execution? It is nearly impossible to beat modern compilers at optimisation. Saving time by typing less? You lost much more time by getting caught by the problems you caused. Obfuscating your code? That succeeded, kind of - you successfully confused yourself.

Comment: Note that the `break` (probably) breaks the score calculation.  It stops the computation at the first difference.  You almost certainly need to go through the whole list and only count those that are the same, so the loop should be `for (i=0;i<10;i++){ if (simonPattern[i] == userPattern[i]) userScore++; }`.  This counts all the matches.  At least, it seems unfair to give a score of 0 if the first character is different but the rest match, whereas you'd give a score of 9 if the first 9 characters match and the last doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditional operator `?:` and `if` statements aren't compatible replacements.

The conditional operator can only be used with scalar (arithmetic or pointer) operands; it cannot be used for program flow control. So it can't contain `break` and similar. In addition, it comes with a couple of subtle hiccups such as implicit type promotion and operator precedence issues. The only advantage of `?:` over `if` is pretty much that it returns a value.

My rule of thumb is that if you can use `if` instead of `?:`, then do it.

This gives safer and (usually) more readable code. The main use of `?:` is when writing various function-like macros (which is something that should be avoided in the first place). Some rare exceptions exist where `?:` does give more readable code, but my general advice is to just stay clear of it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you are attempting to use the [ternary conditional operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#C) to evaluate to statements. The ternary conditional operator in C must be used to evaluate to values. Additionally, the boolean argument to the conditional operator must also be an expression.

However, some statements actually evaluate to expressions,

```
  int g = 5;
  int a = (g = 4);
  printf("g is %d, a is %d\n", g, a);
```

Will result in the following being printed to the console:

```
g is 4, a is 4
```

These statements also work inside the ternary conditional operator:

```
  int g = 5;
  int a = 1 ? rand() % 5 : (g = 4);
  int c = 0 ? 3 : (g += a);
  printf("g is %d, a is %d, c is %d\n", g, a, c);
```

Which prints

```
g is 8, a is 3, c is 8
```

A good rule to follow is, the conditional operator cannot evaluate to keywords, or compile time elements of code. It can only take *values* as arguments.